# Javascript refresh page or element in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm using Flask to display a list of systems and append some buttons as a row element which perform various functions like disabling the system displayed in the row and delete the record.

When I hit the delete button, the record does get deleted but my redirect isn't working and the page doesn't refresh - how can I do this.

This is my route which handles the delete.

**route.py**

```py
@login_required
@webapp.route('/delete/<myrow_id>', methods=['GET'])
def delete(myrow_id):

    print(f'Deleting item: {myrow_id}')

    Systems.query.filter_by(id=myrow_id).delete()
    db.session.commit()

    # Get new systems object for page render.
    systems = Systems.query.all()
    
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Snippets of relevant HTML showing the delete button element and the Javascript used to call the route.

**page.html**

```html
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id={{ system.id }} onClick="delete_item(this.id)">Remove</button></td>

<script>
    function delete_item(clicked_id)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.get('/delete/' + clicked_id, function(response) {
            // Nothing to handle.
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any function, using a tag . See below:

```
<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id={{ system.id }}> <a href="/delete/{{system.id}}"> Remove </a> </button> </td>
```

Comment: Functionally, that works great - thank you.  Visually however I seem to lose the quality of the Bootstrap button as it adds a hyperlink underline to the text.  I've tried searching around and people suggest adding text-decoration:none; to the style of the href but I can't get it to work.  Any suggestions?


```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id={{ system.id }}> <a style='text-decoration:none;' href="/delete/{{system.id}}">Remove</a> </button>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Maybe try with double quotes like     `<a style='text-decoration:none;'` ?

Comment: Sorry, i mean `"<a style='text-decoration:none"`